# how to make a loop that only stops when a "return" button appears?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a script in python to enter the Siafi website. This scritp has a loop that looks up the appointments to pay for the day, to pay them I have to click on "check all", they are ten per page. We click on execute, open a popup asking if you want to perform or schedule, type "r" to perform and click on "confirm", then it opens a popup to enter code 400 and "confirm", a small popup "wait" and again we have to enter 400 and confirm ten times. After the tenth time a return button appears and then the loop resumes. I created a "for i in range (10):" for it to do the ten digits of the 400 code and confirm. The problem is that when the site is slow it gives an error, and if I put it to wait a few seconds between one typing and another it will waste time. We have to do more than seven thousand of these, ten in ten. My scritp has a loop to search the appointments and makes a for in range (10) on the payments. I would like to create an additional loop to replace the "for i in range (10)" and that it only stop when the "return" button appears, because when this button appears the ten have already been typed.

Here is the snippet of this code:

```
 for i in range(10):
try:
    vinc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')))
    vinc = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')
    vinc.send_keys('400')
    enterElem5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'formComp:buttonConfirmar')))
    enterElem5 = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:buttonConfirmar')
    enterElem5.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)#digitar a vinculação e dar enter, fazer isso dez vezes, ver função range
    time.sleep(int(segundosv))
except:
    time.sleep(6)
    vinc = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')))
    vinc = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:repeatCompromissoLista:0:tableRealizacao:0:subtableVinculacoes:0:vinculacao_input')
    vinc.send_keys('400')
    enterElem5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'formComp:buttonConfirmar')))
    enterElem5 = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:buttonConfirmar')
    enterElem5.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)#digitar a vinculação e dar enter, fazer isso dez vezes, ver função range
    time.sleep(int(segundosv))

enterElem6 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formComp:buttonRetornar')))
enterElem6 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'formComp:buttonRetornar')))
enterElem6 = browser.find_element_by_id('formComp:buttonRetornar')
enterElem6.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
rp = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'formComp:tipoDocHabil_input')))
time.sleep(int(segundos))
```

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOCCr.jpg)

[third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZiMT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following and break out of the while loop on having clicked :)

```
counter = 1
while counter < 200:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_id("button")).click()
        """ Break out of our loop """
        break
    except NoSuchElementException
        """ Increment counter, remove if needed """
        print("Retry: %s"% str(counter))
        counter += 1
```

Comment: I use the "for i in range (10)" only for this "try except" block. This part starting with "enterElem6" remains after completion of "for i in range (10)". I need a loop to override this "for range" until the "return" button (that I identify as "enterElem6") is available to be clicked on.

Comment: Example:
'while i <5:
do it
i = i + 1'
I would like to put a condition on while the "return" button is not found:
do it.

Comment: I inserted inside the "while" block: `if (browser.find_element_by_id ('formComp: buttonBack') == True):             break         else:             continues`But it made a mistake: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="formComp:buttonRetornar"] I need it to stop the loop if it finds element [id = "formComp: buttonBack"], if it does not find, continue the loop.